# How to extract config/views while developing a package for composer/packagist?

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I am creating a stand-alone package at packagist.org, seen this article and it helped me a lot http://blog.jgrossi.com/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/. Can you please help me out **how can I generate views/config** like I want to extract some files outside the vendor directory when someone install my package from packagist by composer command?

Comment: It has been 6 days and no-one answered my question. is it so hard? Please guys help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `views` in your PHP package you should choose what view parser you want to use, or you can even create your own, using `ob_start()`, etc.

I suggest you to take a look how packages do that, maybe checking the Laravel View component. It's not difficult to do that, but once you're creating a package for PHP and not for a specific framework you have to choose how you're going to implement `views`, just that.

Cheers, JG.